# Populate and edit a form with a many to many query

Tags: jquery, flask, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have a form that I used to enter selection ingredient that goes in a recipe. I use a jquery script to allow me to "clone"
the form so that I can enter more than one ingredient.

```
class IngredientListTemplate(Form):
    """
    Template to add a new ingredient to a recipe
    The 2 input are prefilled with the data from the query_factory
    """
    category = QuerySelectField(query_factory=categorylist, get_label=u'category', allow_blank=False)
    ingredient = QuerySelectField(query_factory=ingredientlist, get_label=u'ingredient', allow_blank=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           kwargs['csrf_enabled'] = False
           super(IngredientListTemplate, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class IngredientListForm(Form):
    """
    Display the template
    """
    ingredient_list = FieldList(FormField(IngredientListTemplate), min_entries=1)
```

I then store the result of the selection in a table Recipeingredients which has 3 fields (id, recipe, and many to many ingredient)

```
class Recipeingredients(db.Model):
    """
    #Not sure how to store my list of ingredient
    #I need to obviously store the ingredient_id from Ingredientlist.
    #That might be enough since from the ingredient_id I know the rest...

    """
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    recipe = db.Column(db.String(60), index=False, unique=False)
    ingredient_id = db.relationship( 'Ingredientlist', backref='ingredientlist.id', secondary='taxonomy' )

    def __init__(self, recipe, ingredient_id):
        self.recipe = recipe
        self.ingredient_id = ingredient_id

taxonomy = db.Table(
            'taxonomy',
            db.Column( 'recipe_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey( 'recipeingredients.id' ) ),
            db.Column( 'ingredient_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey( 'ingredientlist.id' ) ),
                    )
```

That part is working and I can then display the content for a specific recipe.

Next I am trying to edit that recipe. I am not sure how to proceed.
Here is what I do:
1/ I query the Recipeingredient table
2/ I pass it to the form and then render the templates

```
@mod.route('/ingredients_selection/<int:recipe_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def ingredient_selection(recipe_id):

    recipe = Recipeingredients.query.get(recipe_id)
    #print recipe.ingredient_id #returns [5, 6, 9, 10, 19, 21, 23]
    form = IngredientListForm(obj=recipe)
    print form.data # returns {'ingredient_list': [{'category': None, 'ingredient': None}]}
```

I can see that the problem is because the query from Recipeingredient is not matching what the form is expecting but I can't see how to make it match.

Am I suppose to recreate the data from the query so that it matches what the form is expecting? or is there a better way to achieve it?